# Launching Terminal app starts XQuartz

Tags: terminal, xquartz

Whenever I start the Terminal app in OS X Lion, XQuartz starts automatically. Is this intentional?

I recently turned off much of the **resume** functionality because too many things were starting without being called. Now, this is the only unexpected one.

Comment: Are you using `ssh` with `X11` forwarding?

Comment: No.  That is, when I start Terminal, X comes up immediately, before I have a chance to start ssh.  Only bash is started at that point. (Once I start ssh, then yes.)

Comment: What is in your .bashrc, .bash_profile etc?

Answer (score 1):

Ouch!

It was indeed something in my .bashrc -- a call to xfontpath.  It got put in there when fink was installed, a mod to call all scripts in /sw/etc/profile.d  There, hidden in there, was the call.

Thanks for pushing me to find it.